# React Native (Track user on following direction (Google Map))

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, direction, react-native-mapbox-gl, heremap-navigation

React Native;
How we can Monitor The google map Tracking So Actually User drive on line or not, E.g.

if i got the direction from Location A to  Location B , So how we can check that User Drive on Line or not.

Basically i can't Monitor it,

E.g

[image: Like as Google Monitor the user Drive on Line , if we D track then ReRoute again.]

Actually i want it in react native,
So anyOne Help me How we can achieve it or any 3rd party Library,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can achieve it through the geofence, If you are ready to use paid library then there is one for ReactNative https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/react-native-background-geolocation

Comment: There is also one https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Method isPointNearLine is Solve my problem.

Code Snippet.

```
import * as geolib from 'geolib';
const returnObj=(latitude,longitude)=>{
  return {latitude, longitude}
}
 const IsLies =  geolib.isPointNearLine(
    returnObj(25.976424, -80.238400), ////point
    returnObj(25.97641, -80.24045), ////start
    returnObj(25.97647,-80.23818), ///end
    20 ////distance in meter
);
```

it will return true and false.

There is another approach is we can user @turf/boolean-point-on-line

Code Snippet

```
var pt = turf.point([74.276089,31.478847]); //// NearPoint

///Note [[Start Point],[NearPoint],[EndPoint]]

var line = turf.lineString([[74.277908,31.479470],[74.276089,31.478847],[74.274402,31.478452]]);
var isPointOnLine = turf.booleanPointOnLine(pt, line);
```

it will also return True and false if Points lies on line.